# Outlook keeps marking emails as Unread. Any fix?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Every 2-3 minutes, my outlook sets a random email in a random folder as unread.I get the tray notification and the icon changes to 'mail received'. I cannot even find the email unless I drill down my 200 folders to find it. I mark my root folder as 'read', it goes away, then comes back 2 minutes later. It is driving me crazy.

I tried disabling COM ad-ins, options in the reading pane. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Many thanks.

Our email service is with GoDaddy and we use IMAP to outlook 365.

Comment: Please check if you have set any rule which may lead to this issue. Then you can refer to the following steps: 1.Open Outlook click on the File tab > Account Settings > Account Settings drop-down button.
2. Double-click on the concerned email account > Click on the More Settings button > Click on the Advanced tab.
3. Check the option under Folders; if the Root folder path box is empty or filled-in.
If the box is empty please type the word Inbox and then click on Apply and/or Ok at the bottom of the box to save the settings. 4. Restart your Outlook and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue since migrating over to the new Outlook platform circa 2023 - version 1.2023.1011.100 - client version 20231013005.23.

This may work...

go to inbox of account >
click on View >
click on View Settings >
click on Mail >
click on Message Handling >
uncheck In the unread filter - "Always keep items unread unless I explicitly mark them as read" >
close pop-up window >
restart Outlook

Hope this helps!